# How can a job create other jobs in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a portion of code that begin creating(in a while sentence) 30 jobs(Max) but the Windows Form is blocked waiting to finish all the "while"(maybe 2000 it) and I want to make it responsive. How can I do it?

Thank you :)

```
while ($subred -ne ($subredmax + 1))
{
    while ($ip1 -ne ($ip2 + 1))
    {
        $linea = [System.Text.StringBuilder]''
        $linea.Append("172.20.") | Out-Null
        $linea.Append($subred) | Out-Null
        $linea.Append(".") | Out-Null
        $linea.Append($ip1) | Out-Null
        if ($ExcArray.Contains([string]$linea))
        {
            [void]$ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        }
        else
        {
            while (@(get-job).Count -gt 30)
            {
                Get-Job | Wait-Job -Any
                $(Get-Job -State 'Completed')  | Remove-Job
            }
            $aux = $linea, $subred, $path
            Start-Job -Name "JobJob" $miprom -ArgumentList $aux
            [void]$ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        }
        $ip1++     
    }
    $subred++
    $ip1 = 50
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Remove-Job
$logs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Exception-To-Array -array $logs -path $path\etc\log.txt
Array-ToTB -tb $Show_Info -array $logs
```

Comment: Try using run spaces instead of jobs

Comment: Thank you. I'll try using run spaces